# how to give phonegap app a valid redirect uri

Tags: facebook, cordova

i am begginner in phonegap and using android studio for editing and running phonegap coding

i have to add facebook login in my phonegapp app ,for this i am using openfb.js plugin 
**link -- https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB**
sucessfully integrated all things but when running **its showing me valid oauth redirect uri error**
**what will be "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" if my project file is saved in computer c drive and not on localhost**

Comment: Same one as to be used for desktop apps should work for Cordova/Phonegap apps as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#logindialog